# Python using filter() with a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

So I have this dict

```
dic = { 0: [3,6,4], 1: [1,1,2], 2: [3,5,3], 3: [1,7,4], 4: [1,3,3], 5: [4,4,6] }
```

and I'd like to create another dictionary where the sum() of each list is > 10 using `filter()` and `lambda` expressions.

Outpout desired: `{ 0: [3,6,4], 2: [3,5,3], 3: [1,7,4], 5: [4,4,6] }`

I tried something like

```
dict(filter(lambda e: sum(e[1]) > 10, dic.items()))
```

but it doesn't work at all

Edit:

Ok, I just solved.

```
dict(filter(lambda e: sum(e[1][::]) > 10, dic.items()))
```

Comment: If you solved it, post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't think there's any difference between `sum(e[1])` and `sum(e[1][::])`. The second one just sums a copy of the list, but the sum is the same.

Comment: your original code works great actually, just had to change the variable names

Comment: You guys are right, didn't notice I didn't change the variable names before, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think its much nicer to use a [dictionary comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html) instead of `dict(filter(...))`:

```
>>> dic = { 0: [3,6,4], 1: [1,1,2], 2: [3,5,3], 3: [1,7,4], 4: [1,3,3], 5: [4,4,6] }
>>> {k: v for k, v in dic.items() if sum(v) > 10}
{0: [3, 6, 4], 2: [3, 5, 3], 3: [1, 7, 4], 5: [4, 4, 6]}
```

Comment: I love comprehensions but would it be slower in this case?

Comment: I agree, the difference over ~1000 iterations is ~100ms on colab (I tested this exact thing yesterday)

Comment: I don't know what's faster, but it's a fact dictionary comprehension is eassier, however the exercise asked for using filter. :(

Comment: @RoadRunner holy moly thats cool, must have been colab resources varying between my tests. Comprehensions are probably the better and more readable/pythonic option in almost all production cases

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track! Only problem is you declared a variable with the name `dict` which is reserved in python:

```py
# changed name to data
data = { 0: [3,6,4], 1: [1,1,2], 2: [3,5,3], 3: [1,7,4], 4: [1,3,3], 5: [4,4,6] }

dict(filter(lambda e: sum(e[1]) > 10, data.items()))
```

Output:

```
{0: [3, 6, 4], 2: [3, 5, 3], 3: [1, 7, 4], 5: [4, 4, 6]}
```

Looks good to me!

I try to avoid using function/object names as variables by using underscores. So instead of `dict = {...}` you could do `person_dict = {...}`.

Comment: The variable name is `dic` not `dict`.

Comment: not when i copied it, must have been edited since then

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter and lambda in the following way to achieve the correct output.

```
dic = { 0: [3,6,4], 1: [1,1,2], 2: [3,5,3], 3: [1,7,4], 4: [1,3,3], 5: [4,4,6] }
threshold = 10
filtered_dic = dict(filter(lambda l: sum(l[1]) > threshold, dic.items()))
print(filtered_dic)
```